# Docusign - Auto Sending Email on form submit

Tags: docusignapi

Im working a Laravel Project where we need to get the form details and send them to users to get sign through docusign. I refereed the PHP SDK but not sure where to get the JWT TOKEN, since the normal authentication is asking for docusign credentials each time when submit, we planned to use JWT authentication, please correct me if their are any options apart for this. Reviewed the Rest API, they mentioning the JWT will expire in 1hr, so should we manually generate JWT every 1hr. Please let me know wat is the best approach for handling this.

Answer (score 0):

with JWT, you only need consent once in a lifetime and then you can generate tokens whenever you need.
You can get started by cloning [this repo](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php) and following instructions to see how DocuSign APIs work with JWT.

The relevant code for getting a [JWT token using PHP](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/77ebcc0a936e416ef28f6fd8684548bba1dc0c6b/src/Services/JWTService.php) is this:

```
public function login() {
        self::$access_token = $this->configureJwtAuthorizationFlowByKey();
        self::$expiresInTimestamp = time() + self::$expires_in;

        if(is_null(self::$account)) {
            self::$account = self::$apiClient->getUserInfo(self::$access_token->getAccessToken());
        }

        $redirectUrl = false;
        if (isset($_SESSION['eg'])) {
            $redirectUrl = $_SESSION['eg'];
        }

        self::authCallback($redirectUrl);
    }
```

To gain consent, open a browser (only once needed) with this URL - https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=<YOUR_INT_KEY>&redirect_uri=<YOUR_REDIRECT_URI>

Comment: I'm receiving the following error when I authenticate via JWT  Fatal error: Uncaught DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body: O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:5:"error";s:16:"consent_required";} in D:\xamp\htdocs\code-examples-php-master\code-examples-php-master\vendor\docusign\esign-client\src\Client\ApiClient.php:330

Comment: I have updated the ds_client_id, ds_impersonated_user_id, private_key on the $JWT_CONFIG[] in the ds_config.php. Should I need to do anything appart from this to fix the issue.

Comment: Consent is required once, per app, per user. You need to consent to the app. do you know how to do that?

Comment: No actually this is first time we using, can u help me to do that.

Comment: Actually has I said initally the scope is to convert the form entries to PDF and send to multiple users for getting sign via docusign. Can u let me know wat is the best way we can handle it. The form we build is in laravel(PHP) using AJAX.

Comment: you are doing the right thing, you just need to get consent. You can do that by going (once, manually) to this URL: https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=<YOUR_INT_KEY>&redirect_uri=<YOUR_REDIRECT_URI>

Comment: Tried that, received Invalid OAuth state on the screen and in URL I see access token.  Is that right, should we add this anywhere on the SDK. On navigating to this URL localhost/code-examples-php-master/public/index.php and selecting JWT throws error. Am I missing anything.

Comment: Thanks. Consent is working now. But on the sample SDK flow a dropdown asking for authentication type everytime, on my application once the form is submitted it should send email instead of asking the authentication type and need JSON response how should I implement it here.

Comment: are you using the UI from the repo I posted in the answer? that UI is not for final use, it's for demonstration purposes. You dont' need this drop-down in your real app.

Comment: Tried the Bulk sending envelopes to multiple recipients from PHP Code Examples, email is sending to 2 users but for only first users its showing option for sign. We need 2 sign fields were 2 users sign on the same document. How to do this

Comment: you can add as many recipients and make as many of them be signers and not CC. Just change the code to fit your needs.

Comment: Also, you keep asking questions about different things. It's best practice on stackoverflow to use one question for one topic. If answered - mark so and ask more questions as needed.

Comment: Actually my question was how to auto send email on form submit, I faced some more queries on working this, so asked them on the comments. Actually I already set the recipients to users but it looks like setting needs to set on backed, will look deep on it and thanks for the clarifications provided.

Comment: I explained you do this with remote signing. not sure what you mean by "set on backend" what is?